# How to create an animation with rarity of it to appear together with animations that always appear?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

How to create an animation with rarity of it to appear together with animations that always appear?

Example here:

[image]

The number **1** has a rare chance to appear, let's say 40% chance. When it doesn't appear, it will start with **2** then after the animation of 2 is done **3** will start.

Should it **1** make it through the chance, it will appear and move up and after its animation is done, **2** will play and then after 2, **3** will play. So they just blend in as example.

**2** and **3** will always appear, but **1** has a 40% for it to appear, as example. On **3** I've managed to put a random background chance on it. I've commented it on the code.

Should **1** not appear, then it should act like `display: none`. When I put `display: none` however on box1, the animation never starts, or it started but I can't see it, but I put it in the keyframes.

What I'm thinking is that, I guess it requires Javascript so it can change the `animation-delay` CSS property, I'm not sure though.

This is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/edy3xjvz/2/

```js
var box1 = document.getElementById("box1"); /* The one with the rarity */

var box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
var box3 = document.getElementById("box3"); /* Maybe give it a chance of which color */

var boxes = document.getElementById("boxes");

var box3Colors = {"blue": 90, "red": 50}; /* Blue has 90% chance and red has 50% not sure if done right, but what if I want to add a "green" with the chance of 90% too like "blue"???  */


/* Probably has to be done here, or when reaching a certain area, maybe with a button */
/*document.onload*/

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", startAnimation);

boxes.style.display = "none";

function randomizerWithChances(input) {
    var array = [];
    for(var item in input) {
        if ( input.hasOwnProperty(item) ) {
            for( var i=0; i<input[item]; i++ ) {
                array.push(item);
            }
        }
    }
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}


/* Start Animation */
function startAnimation() {
 boxes.style.display = "none"; /* to replay but doesn't work*/
  
 /* Do radomize stuff */
  /* Don't really know for box1 */
  
 
  /* I've tried box3, like that before
  var random2 = box3Colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * box3Colors.length)]
  box3.style.backgroundColor = random2;*/
  box3.style.backgroundColor = randomizerWithChances(box3Colors);

 /* Animation starts here */
 boxes.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#boxes {
  
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#box1 {background: #00afe8;}
#box2 {background: green;}
#box3 {background: blue;}

@keyframes box1-up {
  0% { top: 70px; position: relative; visibility: visible;}
  100% {top: 0px; position: relative; visibility: visible;}
}

@keyframes blend {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}


#box1 {
  top: 70px;
  /* display: none; Can't start with this I wanted that when it isn't there, it should not appear but with display: none it didn't work because it can never appear then */
  /*position: absolute; visibility: hidden;*/ /* So had to use this but when using this
                                             it didn't work the box is somehow upside 
                                             https://i.imgur.com/3vER5ja.png so not sure */
  animation: box1-up 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


#box2 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: blend 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

#box3 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: blend 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box3" class="box"></div>
</div>


<button id="btn" style="margin-top: 200px;">Start Animation</button>
```

Below there should be a button. What I've tried is to put a randomizer for *box3* background color, seemed to work. I've tried to use *box1* but `display: none` broke it.

I've tried to make something that when the animation doesn't start at all, that box2 is like not here, but when I use `display: none` the animation never starts not sure why.
https://jsfiddle.net/edy3xjvz/3/

Then I removed it so this is what you seen on the snippet above. https://jsfiddle.net/edy3xjvz/4/

Comment: Oh, apperantly position and display can not really be used in animations. Is that correct? What's about hovering, hmm?

So I guess I have to put a class on it and when the animation starts it has to obtain a visible class with display: inline-block as example. But is that actually really needed?

Comment: The position can be animated. The `display` property cannot. Also `display: none` is essentially removing the element from the DOM. If you want to hide or show something but have it maintain its place in the DOM, use `opacity` or `visible` properties.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suspect happend with DOM, but when hover or something that doesn't happen hm? But I want to take it out of the flow.

Comment: https://www.impressivewebs.com/animate-display-block-none/

Comment: Correct so in that link they're toggling `display:none` AND `opacity:0` so the element exists in the DOM and THEN animates its opacity.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the phrase "an animation with rarity of it to appear together" means. I think you mean "an animation with a random chance to appear together", but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the animation handling, as in how it should be randomized and then what happens with the other animations, has to be kinda done manually but you can save the values or get them.

But that what I made is basically a basic concept and you can do even more stuff, but you have to adjust the delays and all that stuff.

This is the first concept:

https://jsfiddle.net/8z9obyLh/

Also you have to notice that once display is gone that the delay will start from there depending on which element just got out of display none.

The other one has a bit complex way but just look at it and how it's done.

Tbh, there should be another way to do this, which I think there is.

https://jsfiddle.net/d25kx6cj/5/

```js
var box1 = document.getElementById("box1"); /* The one with the rarity */

var box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
var box3 = document.getElementById("box3"); /* Maybe give it a chance of which color */

var boxes = document.getElementById("boxes");

var box3Colors = {"blue": 90, "red": 50};

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", toggleAnimation);

boxes.classList.add("deactivated");

function randomizerWithChances(input) {
    var array = [];
    for(var item in input) {
        if ( input.hasOwnProperty(item) ) {
            for( var i=0; i<input[item]; i++ ) {
                array.push(item);
            }
        }
    }
    /*console.log(array)
    var randomizerValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    console.log(randomizerValue)*/
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

function propertyFromStylesheet(selector, attribute) {
    var value;

    [].some.call(document.styleSheets, function (sheet) {
        return [].some.call(sheet.rules, function (rule) {
            if (selector === rule.selectorText) {
                return [].some.call(rule.style, function (style) {
                    if (attribute === style) {
                        value = rule.style.getPropertyValue(attribute);
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                });
            }

            return false;
        });
    });

    return value;
}

var box1_defaultDurs = propertyFromStylesheet("#box1", "animation-duration");
var box2_defaultDur = parseFloat(propertyFromStylesheet("#box2", "animation-duration"));
var box4_defaultDur = parseFloat(propertyFromStylesheet("#box4", "animation-duration"));
var box3_defaultDurs = propertyFromStylesheet("#box3", "animation-duration");

var box1AppearChance = {no:6, yes:4} /* 40% Appear chance I guess*/
var box4AppearChance = {no:8, yes:2}

/*
defaultDurs.split(",").map(function(item) {
  return item.trim();
});*/

var box1_defaultDur = box1_defaultDurs.split(",").map(function(item) {
  return item.trim();
});
var box3_defaultDur = box3_defaultDurs.split(",").map(function(item) {
  return item.trim();
});


var box1_defaultDurStart = parseFloat(box1_defaultDur[0]);
var box1_defaultDurEnd = parseFloat(box1_defaultDur[1]);

var box3_defaultDurStart = parseFloat(box3_defaultDur[0]);
var box3_defaultDurEnd = parseFloat(box3_defaultDur[1]);

var box3_delays = [];


function animationHandler() {
  box3.style.backgroundColor = randomizerWithChances(box3Colors);
  
  var box1Value = randomizerWithChances(box1AppearChance);
  var box4Value = randomizerWithChances(box4AppearChance);
  /*console.log(box1Value)*/
  
  box3_delays[0] = "0s"; /* Put first delay value */
  
  if (box1Value == "yes") {
   box1.classList.add("active");
    
    box2.style.animationDelay = box1_defaultDurStart + "s";
    box3_delays[0] = box1_defaultDurStart + "s";
 }
 
 if (box1Value == "yes" || box4Value == "yes") {
   box3_delays[0] = parseFloat(box3_delays[0]) + box2_defaultDur + "s";
  }
  
    /*box3.style.animationDelay = box3_defaultDurs.split(",").map(function(item) {
     var itemTrimmed = item.trim();

     return parseFloat(itemTrimmed) + box1_defaultDurStart + box2_defaultDur + "s";
    });
  }*/
  /* Use this incase you have to summarize something with two delays, if it has 0s you might want to do something else or check if it's the first one in the array just to leave it alone. But in this case I didn't needed it */
  
 
 /* box4.style.animationDelay = "0s"; To prevent NaN 
 Don't do this it it just breaks it just check it
 */
  
  if (box4Value == "yes") {
   box4.classList.add("active");
    
    if ( isNaN(parseFloat(box2.style.animationDelay)) ) {
     box4.style.animationDelay = box2_defaultDur + "s";
    }
    else if ( !isNaN(parseFloat(box2.style.animationDelay)) ) {
      box4.style.animationDelay = parseFloat(box2.style.animationDelay) + box2_defaultDur + "s";
    } /* box4 doesn't have a delay and we set one */
    
   box3_delays[0] = parseFloat(box3_delays[0]) + box4_defaultDur + "s";
    /* Delay of box3 is getting extended because of box4 when it appears */
 }


  if (box1Value == "yes" || box4Value == "yes") {
   box3.style.animationDelay = [ parseFloat(box3_delays[0]) + "s", parseFloat(box3_delays[0]) + parseFloat(box3_defaultDurStart) + "s" ];
  }
  
 if (box1Value == "yes") {
   if (box4Value == "no") {
      box1.style.animationDelay = ["0s", box2_defaultDur + box3_defaultDurStart + box1_defaultDurStart + box3_defaultDurEnd + "s"]
    }
    else {
     box1.style.animationDelay = ["0s", box2_defaultDur + box3_defaultDurStart + parseFloat(box4.style.animationDelay) + box1_defaultDurStart + box3_defaultDurEnd + "s"];
    }
    /* The + 2 is because of the box1_defaultDurStart which is needed */
    /* And box3_defaultDurEnd also needed in this case */
 }
}

function animationHandlerReset() { 
 box1.classList.remove("active");
  box4.classList.remove("active"); /* And don't forget to remove the class at the end*/
  
  /* Reset to default to stylesheet */
  box1.style.removeProperty("animation-delay");
  box2.style.removeProperty("animation-delay");
  box3.removeAttribute("style"); /* or you could do this if you didn't give it any inline style by default */
  box4.style.removeProperty("animation-delay");
} 


function toggleAnimation() {
 if (!boxes.classList.contains("deactivated")) {
   animationHandlerReset();
  boxes.classList.add("deactivated");
    btn.innerHTML = "Start Animation";
  }
  else if (boxes.classList.contains("deactivated")) {
   animationHandler();
   boxes.classList.remove("deactivated");
    btn.innerHTML = "Stop Animation"
  }
}
```

```css
#boxes {
  
}

.active {
  display: inline-block!important;
}

.deactivated {
  display: none!important;
  /*visibility: hidden!important;*/
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#box1 {background: #00afe8;}
#box2 {background: green;}
#box3 {background: blue;}
#box4 {background: orange;}

@keyframes box1-up {
  0% { top: 70px;}
  100% {top: 0px;}
}

@keyframes box1-down {
  0% { top: 0px;}
  100% {top: 70px; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes box4-anim {
  0% { height: 50px; width: 50px; transform: scale(0.5) rotate(0deg); }
  100% { height: 50px; width: 50px; transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg); }
}

@keyframes blend {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}


#box1 {
  top: 70px;
  display: none;
  animation: box1-up 2s, box1-down 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


#box2 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: blend 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*animation-delay: 3s;*/
}

#box3 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: blend 3s, blend 4s reverse;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 3s, 6s; /* Both delays start together. Probably you want the other delay to be the twice as the size of the first one in this case for the end, but maybe not everytime */
}

#box4 {
  display: none;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  animation: box4-anim 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box4" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box3" class="box"></div>
</div>


<button id="btn" style="margin-top: 200px;">Start Animation</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick PoC of how it could behave with our without box1 if I'm understanding your description correctly so that if the `active` class is there it will look as you have it, and if not then give the illusion equivalent of `display: none`, hope it helps, cheers.

```js
const box1 = document.getElementById('box1');

toggleActive = () => {
  let classes = box1.classList;
  classes.contains('active') ? classes.remove('active') : classes.add('active');
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: lightgray 1px dashed;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.container div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  background-color: lime;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: reveal 3s ease forwards;
}

.container div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.container div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.container div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

#box1 {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translateY(6rem);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

#box1.active {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  animation: revealUp 2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes reveal {
  to { opacity: 1 }
}

@keyframes revealUp {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="box1" class="active"></div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
  <div id="box3"></div>
</div>

<br/>

<button onclick="toggleActive()">Toggle First One</button>
```

Comment: I see, yeah guess it has to be done with the class, the only remaining question the rarity. I guess it works the same?

Comment: Ya (if I'm understanding your intent that is) then if box1 is not there, then 2 & 3 still fade in the same and consume the space that 1 would take. If box1 has class active then it slides in and 2 and 3 fade in sequentially to its side.

Comment: Yes, that is it.

Comment: @Viaoer43 cool, if your question is answered remember to click the checkmark thingy next to vote thing to mark it answered so folks know you get your remedy, if not just let us know the issue and you'll get sorted. Have a great weekend!

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out if I did the rarity correctly on the box, if yes I guess I can try to do the "checking"